# First import test of Rally / Bugzilla connector

Tags: rally, bugzilla

I'm having problems making my first import of bugs from Bugzilla to Rally.  This is not normally something that I work with (I'm normally in the dark lands of firmware), so I apologize for anything stupid/idiotic in what I've done so far.  I've managed to get the services working, however now I am out of my depth and can't find anything that can help me continue.

Lets start with some background information... I followed mainly the instalation instructions from [mozilla](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:BzAPI#Required_Extension_and.2For_Patch.28es.29) and https://help.rallydev.com/bugzilla-installation-user-guide

- Bugzilla 4.4 on remote linux server with extension installed
- bzapi running locally (windows)
- executing rally2_bugzilla_connector locally.

In the log file when running the service UPDATE_BUGZILLA_TO_RALLY its returning that its found 0 bugs which I guess is correct as there are no bugs in Rally yet. When moving to the COPY_BUGZILLA_TO_RALLY service however is where things start to fall apart.  I can't glean anyting from the log messages - I'll attach that below.  I have a few suspects but I would think that the log messages would be different if it were these, but I'll share them with you:

- I have just the default field mappings (for now) and haven't added any enum field mapping either, though I plan to once I get it working. (I don't know if I already need to do this to get it to work!)
- Another setup that I'm not totally sure if it was concluded correctly is the cf_rally_id field in the sql server.  When running the query on the database it didn't find any rows being null. (The bugzilla database is postgres and the sql query was adapted from the original.

The connector configuration file and output log follows:

```
<Config>
<RallyConnection>
    <Url>rally1.rallydev.com</Url>
    <WorkspaceName>Workspace</WorkspaceName>
    <Projects>
        <Project>Project</Project>
    </Projects>
    <User>me</User>
    <Password>my password</Password>
    <ArtifactType>Defect</ArtifactType>
    <ExternalIDField>BugzillaID</ExternalIDField>
    <CrosslinkUrlField>BugzillaLink</CrosslinkUrlField>

</RallyConnection>

<BugzillaConnection>
    <Url>127.0.0.1:3000</Url>
    <User>me</User>
    <Password>mypassword</Password>
    <ArtifactType>bug</ArtifactType>
    <IDField>id</IDField>
    <ExternalIDField>cf_rally_id</ExternalIDField>
</BugzillaConnection>

<Connector>
    <FieldMapping>
        <Field><Rally>Name</Rally>         <Other>summary</Other></Field>
        <Field><Rally>State</Rally>        <Other>status</Other></Field>
        <Field><Rally>Severity</Rally>     <Other>severity</Other></Field>
        <Field><Rally>Priority</Rally>     <Other>priority</Other></Field>
    </FieldMapping>
</Connector>

<ConnectorRunner>
    <Preview>False</Preview>
    <LogLevel>Debug</LogLevel>
    <Services>UPDATE_BUGZILLA_TO_RALLY, COPY_BUGZILLA_TO_RALLY</Services>
</ConnectorRunner>
```

```
************************************************************************************************************

 rally2_bugzilla_connector  version: 4.4.6-76
     pid: 8932
     starting at: 2014-08-29 19:32:05 Z
     cwd: C:/Program Files (x86)/RallyConnectorforBugzilla
     configs: bz_config.xml
     interval: -1
     Work Item Connector Hub    version: 0.4.3-273-master/master
     RallyConnection      spoke version: 4.2.1 using rally_api gem version 1.0.1
     BugzillaConnection   spoke version: 4.4.6-76-master using rally-bzapi gem version 0.1.7
************************************************************************************************************
[2014-08-29 19:32:05 Z]   ANY : RallyEIF::WRK::ConnectorRunner.block in run - processing to commence using content from bz_config.xml
[2014-08-29 19:32:05 Z]   ANY : Class.read_config_file - bz_config.xml last modified   2014-08-29 19:31:12 UTC, size: 1872 chars
[2014-08-29 19:32:05 Z]   ANY : RallyEIF::WRK::RallyConnection.initialize - Initializing Rally connection version 4.2.1
[2014-08-29 19:32:05 Z]  INFO : RallyEIF::WRK::RallyConnection.initialize - Rally Web Services version 1.42
[2014-08-29 19:32:05 Z]   ANY : RallyEIF::WRK::BugzillaConnection.initialize -       Initializing Bugzilla connection version 4.4.6
[2014-08-29 19:32:05 Z]  INFO : RallyEIF::WRK::Connector.initialize - Ruby platform i386-mingw32
[2014-08-29 19:32:05 Z]  INFO : RallyEIF::WRK::Connector.initialize - Ruby version 2.0.0
[2014-08-29 19:32:05 Z]  INFO : RallyEIF::WRK::BugzillaConnection.connect - Connecting to Bugzilla
[2014-08-29 19:32:06 Z]  INFO : RallyEIF::WRK::BugzillaConnection.connect - rally-bzapi version 0.1.7
[2014-08-29 19:32:06 Z]  INFO : RallyEIF::WRK::BugzillaConnection.connect - Connected to Bugzilla at 127.0.0.1:3000 (version 4.4)
[2014-08-29 19:32:06 Z]  INFO : RallyEIF::WRK::RallyConnection.connect - Connecting to Rally
[2014-08-29 19:32:06 Z] DEBUG : RallyEIF::WRK::RallyConnection.connect - In connect begin clause - connecting to Rally via rally_api
[2014-08-29 19:32:09 Z] DEBUG : RallyEIF::WRK::RallyConnection.connect - Looking up projects
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z]  INFO : RallyEIF::WRK::RallyConnection.connect - Connected to Rally at https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm -  Workspace: Workspace
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z]  INFO : RallyEIF::WRK::RallyConnection.connect -   Projects: Project
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z]  INFO : RallyEIF::WRK::Connector.validate - Beginning validation
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z] DEBUG : RallyEIF::WRK::RallyConnection.validate - Rally Connection - user entry "me" detected in config file
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z] DEBUG : RallyEIF::WRK::RallyConnection.validate - Rally Connection - password entry detected in config file
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z] DEBUG : RallyEIF::WRK::RallyConnection.validate - Rally Connection - artifact type "defect" validated
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z] DEBUG : RallyEIF::WRK::RallyConnection.validate - Rally IDField name of "ObjectID" validated
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z] DEBUG : RallyEIF::WRK::RallyConnection.validate - Rally ExternalIDField name of "BugzillaID" validated
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z] DEBUG : RallyEIF::WRK::RallyConnection.validate - Rally CrossLinkUrlField name of "BugzillaLink" validated
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z] DEBUG : RallyEIF::WRK::RallyConnection.validate - Rally Connection - FieldHandler target fields existence validated
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z] DEBUG : RallyEIF::WRK::RallyConnection.validate - Rally Connection - Field Defaults settings validated
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z] DEBUG : RallyEIF::WRK::Connector.validate - RallyConnection validate succeeded
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z] DEBUG : RallyEIF::WRK::BugzillaConnection.validate - Bugzilla Connection - user entry "me" detected in config file
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z] DEBUG : RallyEIF::WRK::BugzillaConnection.validate - Bugzilla Connection - password entry detected in config file
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z] DEBUG : RallyEIF::WRK::BugzillaConnection.validate - Bugzilla Connection - artifact type "bug" validated
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z] DEBUG : RallyEIF::WRK::BugzillaConnection.validate - Bugzilla IDField name of "id" validated
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z] DEBUG : RallyEIF::WRK::BugzillaConnection.validate - Bugzilla ExternalIDField name of "cf_rally_id" validated
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z] DEBUG : RallyEIF::WRK::BugzillaConnection.validate - Bugzilla Connection - FieldHandler target fields existence validated
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z] DEBUG : RallyEIF::WRK::BugzillaConnection.validate - Bugzilla Connection - Field Defaults settings validated
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z] DEBUG : RallyEIF::WRK::Connector.validate - Bugzilla Connection validate succeeded
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z] DEBUG : RallyEIF::WRK::Connector.block in validate - RallyConnection field_mapping target "Name" existence validated
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z] DEBUG : RallyEIF::WRK::Connector.block in validate - Bugzilla Connection field_mapping target "summary" existence validated
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z] DEBUG : RallyEIF::WRK::Connector.block in validate - RallyConnection field_mapping target "State" existence validated
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z] DEBUG : RallyEIF::WRK::Connector.block in validate - Bugzilla Connection field_mapping target "status" existence validated
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z] DEBUG : RallyEIF::WRK::Connector.block in validate - RallyConnection field_mapping target "Severity" existence validated
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z] DEBUG : RallyEIF::WRK::Connector.block in validate - Bugzilla Connection field_mapping target "severity" existence validated
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z] DEBUG : RallyEIF::WRK::Connector.block in validate - RallyConnection field_mapping target "Priority" existence validated
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z] DEBUG : RallyEIF::WRK::Connector.block in validate - Bugzilla Connection field_mapping target "priority" existence validated
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z] DEBUG : RallyEIF::WRK::Connector.validate - Rally CrosslinkUrlField name of "BugzillaLink" validated
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z]  INFO : RallyEIF::WRK::Connector.validate - Validation complete
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z]   ANY : RallyEIF::WRK::ConnectorRunner.run_services - Last Run 2014-08-29 19:27:10 UTC  --- Now 2014-08-29 19:32:10 UTC
[2014-08-29 19:32:10 Z]   ANY : RallyEIF::WRK::ConnectorRunner.process_service -     Starting Service UPDATE_BUGZILLA_TO_RALLY
[2014-08-29 19:32:12 Z]  INFO : RallyEIF::WRK::BugzillaConnection.find_updates -   Found 0 updated bugs in Bugzilla
[2014-08-29 19:32:12 Z]  INFO : RallyEIF::WRK::ConnectorRunner.show_preview_message - ------- Preview Mode -------
[2014-08-29 19:32:12 Z]  INFO : RallyEIF::WRK::ConnectorRunner.show_preview_message - Found 0 records in Bugzilla
[2014-08-29 19:32:12 Z]   ANY : RallyEIF::WRK::ConnectorRunner.process_service - Finished Service UPDATE_BUGZILLA_TO_RALLY
[2014-08-29 19:32:12 Z]   ANY : RallyEIF::WRK::ConnectorRunner.process_service - Starting Service COPY_BUGZILLA_TO_RALLY
[2014-08-29 19:32:19 Z] ERROR : RallyEIF::WRK::ConnectorRunner.rescue in run_services - Unexpected exception occurred
[2014-08-29 19:32:19 Z] ERROR : RallyEIF::WRK::ConnectorRunner.exception - Message undefined local variable or method `raw_bugs' for   #<RallyEIF::WRK::BugzillaConnection:0x337d820>
[2014-08-29 19:32:19 Z] ERROR : RallyEIF::WRK::ConnectorRunner.exception - Stack Trace
[2014-08-29 19:32:19 Z] ERROR : RallyEIF::WRK::ConnectorRunner.block in exception - C:/Users/KARLST~1/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrC3F3.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rallyeif-bz-4.4.6/lib/rallyeif/bz/bz_connection/bugzilla_connection.rb:300:in `rescue in find_by_query'
[2014-08-29 19:32:19 Z] ERROR : RallyEIF::WRK::ConnectorRunner.block in exception - C:/Users/KARLST~1/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrC3F3.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rallyeif-bz-4.4.6/lib/rallyeif/bz/bz_connection/bugzilla_connection.rb:297:in `find_by_query'
[2014-08-29 19:32:19 Z] ERROR : RallyEIF::WRK::ConnectorRunner.block in exception - C:/Users/KARLST~1/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrC3F3.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rallyeif-bz-4.4.6/lib/rallyeif/bz/bz_connection/bugzilla_connection.rb:153:in `find_new'
[2014-08-29 19:32:19 Z] ERROR : RallyEIF::WRK::ConnectorRunner.block in exception - C:/Users/KARLST~1/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrC3F3.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rallyeif-wrk-0.4.3/lib/rallyeif/wrk/connector_runner.rb:307:in `process_service'
[2014-08-29 19:32:19 Z] ERROR : RallyEIF::WRK::ConnectorRunner.block in exception - C:/Users/KARLST~1/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrC3F3.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rallyeif-wrk-0.4.3/lib/rallyeif/wrk/connector_runner.rb:390:in `block in run_services'
[2014-08-29 19:32:19 Z] ERROR : RallyEIF::WRK::ConnectorRunner.block in exception - C:/Users/KARLST~1/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrC3F3.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rallyeif-wrk-0.4.3/lib/rallyeif/wrk/connector_runner.rb:389:in `each'
[2014-08-29 19:32:19 Z] ERROR : RallyEIF::WRK::ConnectorRunner.block in exception - C:/Users/KARLST~1/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrC3F3.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rallyeif-wrk-0.4.3/lib/rallyeif/wrk/connector_runner.rb:389:in `run_services'
[2014-08-29 19:32:19 Z] ERROR : RallyEIF::WRK::ConnectorRunner.block in exception - C:/Users/KARLST~1/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrC3F3.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rallyeif-wrk-0.4.3/lib/rallyeif/wrk/connector_runner.rb:243:in `block in run'
[2014-08-29 19:32:19 Z] ERROR : RallyEIF::WRK::ConnectorRunner.block in exception - C:/Users/KARLST~1/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrC3F3.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rallyeif-wrk-0.4.3/lib/rallyeif/wrk/connector_runner.rb:204:in `each'
[2014-08-29 19:32:19 Z] ERROR : RallyEIF::WRK::ConnectorRunner.block in exception - C:/Users/KARLST~1/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrC3F3.tmp/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rallyeif-wrk-0.4.3/lib/rallyeif/wrk/connector_runner.rb:204:in `run'
[2014-08-29 19:32:19 Z] ERROR : RallyEIF::WRK::ConnectorRunner.block in exception - C:/Users/KARLST~1/AppData/Local/Temp/ocrC3F3.tmp/src/rally2_bugzilla_connector.rb:12:in `<main>'
[2014-08-29 19:32:19 Z]   ANY : RallyEIF::WRK::ConnectorRunner.block in log_service_statistics - bz_config.xml: 0 items updated from Bugzilla to Rally (Preview Mode)
[2014-08-29 19:32:19 Z]   ANY : RallyEIF::WRK::ConnectorRunner.log_service_statistics - bz_config.xml: service run took 13 seconds
```

Any ideas?

Cheers

[Edit]  Some more information: I noticed that I'm getting a lot of utf8 - unicode mapping errors generated from the bzapi script.  Bugzilla is configured as UTF8 (as required) and has Brazilian Portuguese language entries.  All are similar to: "utf8 "\xE1" does not map to Unicode at C:/strawberry/perl/site/lib/Text/CSV_XS.pm line 779,  line 2."

Comment: After checking if the bzapi was working properly using this process http://rallydev.force.com/answers?id=kA114000000Phw4 It shows that I haven't configured the fastcgi server correctly.  Currently working on this!

Comment: drong0 can you let me know how did you configure your bugzilla am getting the error can't connect to bugzilla

Comment: Srinivas, I need more information.  What isn't connecting?  rally2_bugzilla_connector?